# Компьютерная мышка

Tags: грамотная-речь, терминология

Раньше я не сталкивался с тем, чтобы компьютерную мышку называли мышью, а потом иногда стал слышать такое и даже в словарях попалась она как *мышь.*

Скажите, так её называли с са́мого её появления или всё-таки не зря мне такое режет слух и изначально была только мышка?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131401/discussion-on-question-by----).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Уф-ф! Странно, чегой-то вас слишком быстро пнули в чат. Мышь (именно **мышь**, объёмная, без *ковра* (не коврика!), собственно, и не фунциклирующая) появилась в моей работе в 1993 году. Спасибо за вопрос — я вернулась на кучу лет назад!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, мне можно было и без собачки, это же комментарии к моему же вопросу. В чат отправили, видимо, потому что было ещё много комментариев, которые мы поудаляли. Очень интересный у тебя опыт! *Фунциклировать* — раньше такого даже и не слышал, спасибо за словечко. :) И спасибо за плюсик! Мне почему-то уже много дней их не ставили ни за что.

Comment: Вот то правило: https://i.imgur.com/1bEWWxZ.png

Comment: Спасибо! А откуда ты берёшь эти ссылки?

Comment: Это сайт, куда можно загрузить изображение. Он один из лучших, если не лучший. Система этого сайта тоже им пользуется (когда вставляешь изображение).

Comment: Ну хорошо, я так сначала и подумал, что сайт, потом забыл об этом. А грузишь из книжки, что ли?

Comment: Ну конечно, сайт, любая ссылка ведёт на сайт. Иначе подумать нельзя было)

Comment: Ничего не понял. Откуда грузишь?

Comment: Спросил, откуда ссылки. Говорю, что это сайт, куда можно загрузить изображение. Говоришь, что так и подумал сначала. Говорю, что иначе нельзя было подумать. || Есть классная программа для скриншотов, с неё, ею объединил фрагменты, и стало целиком.

Comment: Ну я тебя спрашиваю, откуда ты берёшь это!

Comment: Беру из книжки.

Answer (score 2):

В советской литературе 80-х встречается исключительно «мышь», причём в более ранних даже в форме *«Манипулятор [типа] “мышь”».* В различных произведениях бюрократического языка (а также как пародия на них) такая форма до сих пор иногда встречается. Так что несомненно, что изначальной формой является именно «мышь». Современные словари также отдают предпочтение «мыши».

Сложно сказать, когда появился жаргонизм «мышка». Вероятно, практически сразу, так как это выглядит довольно естественно. В НКРЯ [самое раннее](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcG9zdDE5NTAva29tbWVyc2FudC9zdG9saXRzYTE5OTcvMDY0NzQzNjEueG1s&lang=ru&mode=main&mycorp=JSONeyJkb2NfaV95ZWFyX2NyZWF0ZWQiOiBbIjE5OTcxOTk3Il19&nodia=1&req=%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexform), что удалось найти — 1997. В Google Books<sup>1</sup> — [журнал](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=QK20AAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%22&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjb5L_F4JL0AhUig_0HHYLrApYQ6AF6BAgCEAI) 1994 (хотя «мышка» там взята в кавычки и используется скорее для обыгрывания выражения «серая мышка», а не как самостоятельный термин). Сейчас он повсеместно распространён.

---

<sup>¹ Спасибо *@grizzly* за ссылку</sup>

Comment: Вот чуть раньше — в [1994-м](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=QK20AAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%22&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjb5L_F4JL0AhUig_0HHYLrApYQ6AF6BAgCEAI).

Comment: @grizzly, спасибо, добавил в ответ... жаль страница не полностью доступна...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Забыл отреагировать.